# what is the plural of "GPS"

Tags: grammatical-number, acronyms

Do I have several GPSs, or several GPSes, or something completely different? What is the rule to remember (will be useful later when I can have a GPS2, a GPST and maybe a GPSX too).

Comment: The short answer is that you own several ***GPSes***.  The people who write *GPS’s* tend to get talked about, and not in a good way.